# Flexslider - add/replace div class outside of slider loop for each slide

Tags: jquery, slider, addclass, flexslider

I have 'header' div container outside of slider.
And I have slider images with 'white' or 'black' classes. 
Is it possible to implement the following: After slide loading 'header' container assigned image class (black/white) on the fly.
I have flexslider as background slider under header. When slide image dark header is displayed with light styles. Is it possible?

```
<div class="header"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();  
  });
</script>

<div class="flexslider">  
     <ul class="slides"> 
        <li><img src="someimage.jpg" class="white"/></li>
        <li><img src="someimage.jpg" class="black"/></li>
        <li><img src="someimage.jpg" class="white"/></li>
        <li><img src="someimage.jpg" class="white"/></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry for my english. Thanks